# Reactive spring-data-solr repositories

Tags: java, spring, solr, project-reactor, spring-data-solr

I found a [Blog Post](https://spring.io/blog/2016/11/28/going-reactive-with-spring-data) about spring-data reactive repositories. It was mentioned that, it is currently supported for MongoDB, Apache Cassandra and Redis.

We are going to use spring-data-solr repositories in our reactive (based on vert'x) architecture.

Is it possible to easly get reactive support in this type of repositories? How much effort would it be cost to implement own implementation of reactive solr repostiory?

Comment: Id love to know if there is a support planned too

Answer (score 1):

Probability never, Spring Data for Apache Solr was discontinued, I'd rather recommend you to stop use it and go with native client.

https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/07/spring-data-for-apache-solr-discontinued